# How to get the total size uncompressed of a table in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, json, csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This query shows me that a table represents 1.4TB of compressed data in Snowflake:

```sql
select table_name, row_count, bytes
from snowflake_sample_data.information_schema.tables
where lower(table_name)='store_sales'
and lower(table_schema)='tpcds_sf10tcl'
```

But how can I tell the uncompressed size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uncompressed size of a table will depend on how you represent it.

The following query will sample a number of rows, and estimate how many bytes this data would represent in JSON and CSV format uncompressed:

```sql
select csv/sample_rows*total_rows bytes_csv
    , json/sample_rows*total_rows bytes_json
from (
    select sum(length(csv_line)-1) csv, sum(length(json_line)+1) json, count(*) sample_rows
    from (
        select replace(array_construct(a.*)::string, 'undefined', '') csv_line
          , object_construct(a.*)::string json_line
        from snowflake_sample_data.tpcds_sf10tcl.store_sales a
        -- where ss_cdemo_sk is null
        limit 10000
    )
) a
join (
    select count(*) total_rows
    from snowflake_sample_data.tpcds_sf10tcl.store_sales
) b
```

| BYTES_CSV | BYTES_JSON |
| --- | --- |
| 4,098,101,331,350.31 | 15,130,747,457,587.213 |

Note: -1 for the csv represents removing the 2 brackets and adding a new line, while +1 for the json represents adding a new line.